# String match URI with Lua patterns

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

How do I pattern match these URI's? I need to string match whatever characters are between the first and second slash (1) or any characters that are present after the first slash (2) or just `/`(3).

Note the trailing slash in the first example.

(1)
`/resource/_another-resource`

(2)
`/_resource`

(3)
`/`

I have `uri_resource = uri:match('^%/(.-)%/')` which takes care of example 1 but will fail if no trailing slash is present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
^/([^/]*)
```

It matches: a string starting with `/`, and then captures any characters that's not `/`.

Also note that `/` doesn't need to be escaped.